# Counting the number of unique letters in a string

Tags: java, string, letters

I have to write code that counts how many unique letters are in a string:
e.g

```
"aabbcdefff"
```

This will return 6 as there are 6 different letters in the string. Currently I have the code:

```
  String letters = ("aabbcdefff");              
  char temp = ' ';
   for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++){
      temp = inp.charAt(i);
      if (temp != ' ') {   //doesnt count spaces as letters
        alphabetSize = alphabetSize+1;
          for (int j = 0; j < inp.length(); j++){
            tempInp = tempInp.replace(temp,' ');
        }
      }
    }
```

The idea of this code is that it should when detecting a letter, replace all instances of it with a space. When i run this code however, it just gives me the length of the string. What am i doing wrong? Is there another more elegant way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you want uniqueness, use a "set"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are fine by just using a Set.

Loop over your string, and add each letter to your set. afterwards, check length of your set, and your done.

Comment: This is much easier to implement and has a lower time complexity than your current implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner with Java 8 streaming API:

```
long numberOfDistinctChars = s.chars().distinct().count()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find it using `Linq` service.

Please add `using System.Linq;` Namespace.

```
string str = "TestTest";
int cnt = str.ToLower().ToCharArray().Where(w => w != ' ').Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: question is tagged as java - this is c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using **Java collection (Set)**.

```
Set<Character> result = new HashSet<Character>();

    String letters = ("aabbcdefff");              
       for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++){
          result.add(letters.charAt(i));
        }
```

Your final result is in result set and it is always unique.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be _Set<Character>_?

Comment: Nice, I was forget :)

Comment: Thanks, But when I run the line "Set<Char> set = new HashSet<Char>();" it gives me the error "unchecked and unsafe operation" but reading up a thread that asks this question, it looks like I'm not doing anything wrong?

Comment: You used character or char? Use Character.

Comment: I used the line "Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();" and its giving me a red box over "HashSet"

Comment: Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>(); It works for me. import java.util.Set;

Comment: I worked it out, i had to import HashSet "import java.util.HashSet;" Thanks

Comment: Then accept the answer, It will helps others to find out best answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be converting the string to an array and then using the following method:

```
    String s = "aabbcdefff";

    char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();


    for(char c : charArray){
        if(al.contains(c)){
            al.remove((Character)c);
        }else{
            al.add(c);
        }
    }
```

What ever is left in the array list 'al' are duplicates. The advantage of this method is that it has O(n) runtime